# How to split multiple strings from one row to table and how to add multiple strings to one row using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I would like to know how to separate the string so that the result is like this

```
tax
company name branch #1-0
123456789123456
2022-05-14 01:51:09
38.75
5.05
10-1 / B
Y29tcGFueSBuYW1lIGJyYW5jaCAjMS0wCjEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1NgoyMDIyLTA1LTE0IDAxOjUxOjA5CjM4Ljc1CjUuMDUKMTAtMSAvIEI=
```

I would also like to know how the string is saved in the database

```
{ "SellerName": "company name branch #1-0" , "SellerTaxId": "123456789123456" , "SellerTimeStamp": "2022-05-14 01:51:09" , "TotalInvoiceIncludingTax": "38.75" , "TotalTax": "5.05" ,  "InvoiceNo": "10-1 / B" , "QRCode": "Y29tcGFueSBuYW1lIGJyYW5jaCAjMS0wCjEyMzQ1Njc4OTEyMzQ1NgoyMDIyLTA1LTE0IDAxOjUxOjA5CjM4Ljc1CjUuMDUKMTAtMSAvIEI=" }
```

[image for save to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSrpD.png)

[image for spilt from table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omrV6.png)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? This is a json string and how they are treated depends entirely on the specific database.

Comment: SQL server 2019

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: I'm beginner i don't know too much

Comment: @MohammedAbdelrahman The docs should get you on the right track https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

### ** I fix it by this query thanks **

```
SELECT  
      [ID],
      [TAX],
      JSON_VALUE([TAX],'$.SellerName')as SellerName,
      JSON_VALUE([TAX],'$.SellerTaxId')as SellerTaxId,
      JSON_VALUE([TAX],'$.SellerTimeStamp')as SellerTimeStamp,
      JSON_VALUE([TAX],'$.TotalInvoiceIncludingTax')as TotalInvoiceIncludingTax,
      JSON_VALUE([TAX],'$.TotalTax')as TotalTax,
      JSON_VALUE([TAX],'$.InvoiceNo')as InvoiceNo,
      JSON_VALUE([TAX],'$.QRCode')as QRCode
      
    FROM 
        [fcs_gurban].[dbo].[TaxJosn]
    WHERE
        ISJSON([TAX])>0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).